# Spring Boot configuration behaviour with @ConfigurationProperties and Command Line arguments

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I seem to be having some funny behaviour with Spring boot on yaml property files im trying to load.

I have a Settings bean that is setup as follows :

```
@ConfigurationProperties(location = 'config.yml', prefix='settings')
public class Settings {
    private String path;
    ...
}
```

I've explicitly told spring to look in the config.yml file for property values to bind to the Settings bean.  This looks like this:

```
settings:
   path: /yaml_path
```

This works well, however, I don't seem to be able to override these values from the command line i.e.

```
java -jar my.jar --settings.path=test
```

The value that is bound to the settings bean is still /yaml_path but would've expected that the --settings.path=test would override the settings in the yaml.

Interestingly, I've noticed that if i take comment out the path setting from the yaml file, the commandline argument value of test comes through.

Additionally, I've also noticed that if i change my config file from config.yml to application.yml and remove the 'location' attribute from the configuration properties file this gives me the desired desired behaviour, but means that I can't have multiple application.yml files in the classpath as it breaks my multi module application which has configuration files throughout.

Ideal world I would like be able to have modules read configuration from yaml files that contain safe values for that module (i.e. module.yml) and be able to override these values from the commandline if needed.  Has anyone figured out how to get commandline arguments passed into the beans this way?

I have created a project on git hub to show case the issue

https://github.com/vcetinick/spring-boot-yaml-test

Running the application displays logging information about what settings are applied. i.e.

> java -jar spring-boot-yaml-test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar --config.path=/test

should override the settings, however, the default /var/tmp is displayed

additionally, when using the application.yml configuration

> java -jar spring-boot-yaml-test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar --app.path=/test

seems to behave as expected where the command line argument overrides the value but only works because its value is defined in the application.yml file.

Comment: try -Dsettings.path=test

Comment: Yeah tried that no difference

Comment: Does seem that the locations attribute indicates that the file should take precedence over other sources

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html command line arguments should have the highest precedence

Comment: Exactly what I was expecting, however, that is not whats happening in my case

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the locations attribute is working as designed, however, seems to be at odds with the standard configuration paradigm setup by spring boot (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/5111).  It is meant to override the settings.  It looks like this this feature may be removed in a future release of spring boot anyway (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/5129)